# Deaf and Blind?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who can't hear or see you? As if they are deaf and blind. 
What is a word describing both please?

Thanks

Comment: Too late to inquire I guess, but were you looking for a figurative expression or a noun for a person who is afflicted with both disabilities.

Comment: Normally it's "deaf and blind" or "deaf-blind".  I've never seen a single word.

Answer (score 1):

[deaf-blind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deaf-blind) or deafblind. The condition can be called deafblindness.